# add a movie in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Hello I'm trying to insert in a scene, a cocos 2d project, a movie in the background and a sprite object above it.
I managed to insert the movie and the sprite and interagisono but I can not move the video below spritre as I would like.

The code that I wrote in my scene is as follows:

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
  // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
  CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
  // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
  lLevel0 *layer = [lLevel0 node];
  // add layer as a child to scene
  [scene addChild: layer];
  // return the scene
  return scene;
}
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
  // always call "super" init
  // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
  if( (self=[super init]) ) {

    [self startMovie];
    //Creo un oggetto sulla scena
    sBall *ball = [sBall Ball];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    ball.position = ccp( ball.contentSize.width/2 , size.height/2 );//Carico la
    posizione della palla sulla sinistra (start poosition)
    [self addChild:ball z:999];
    [ball moveForever];
    [self beginDetectingTouch];
  }
  return self;
}
- (void) startMovie
{
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sampleVideo"
  ofType:@"mp4"];
  NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
  MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
  initWithContentURL:movieURL];
  //[[mp moviePlayer] setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
  // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
  object:mp];
  if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(view)]) {
    if([MPMoviePlayerControllerinstancesRespondToSelector:@selector(view)]){
      // Use the new 3.2 style API
      mp.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
      mp.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = FALSE;
      // This does blows up in cocos2d, so we'll resize manually
      // [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
      [mp.moviePlayer.viewsetTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((float)M_PI_2)];
      CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];
      mp.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.height,
      winSize.width); // width and height are swapped after rotation
      [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]addSubview:mp.moviePlayer.view];
      [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]sendSubviewToBack:mp.moviePlayer.view];
      [mp.moviePlayer play];
    }
  } else {
    // Use the old 2.0 style API
    mp.moviePlayer.movieControlMode =MPMovieControlModeHidden;
    [mp.moviePlayer play];
  }
}
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinishs:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```